# php Preg_replace get right closing div

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a webSiteMaker and for my system i have to change back all HTML to valid HTML from the editor so i use this code for example:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\<div id=\"body\">(.*?)<\/div>/ms','<body>\1</body>',$data);
```

But the problem is that their are also other div's inside the body div.
So my preg_replace closes to vast it gets te first  it can see but it's supposed to take the div which closes:

```
<div id="body">
<div class="otherDiv">test</div>
</div>
```

It takes the <./div> from .otherDiv and not from #body please help me?

Comment: Using regex to validate your HTML is not the correct approach. You have to go through all your HTML and fix the issues yourself. No amount of regex will validate it for you. You can use free services to point out any issues you have: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I think its easier to get it on client-side then pass to your server-side script. E.g.: `var send_to_server = document.getElementById('body').innerHTML`

Comment: It should be done in php and its a verry berry big div its a whole webpage @Kazzkiq

Comment: Do you have an online example of your actual complete code?

Comment: My complete code is verry verry big and uses more things than you can imagin xD @fusion3k

Comment: @MennovanHout I wanted to say if there are a complete HTML page online of your old site version. Seeing complete HTML code can help to find a solution.

Comment: @fusion3k Well my scropt is valid HTML but i am working on a online webpagemaker so what it does is it changes the elements to divs so you can change it in the editor i made and now when you save it it should be turned back in valid HTML for being displayed on the custommers site.

Comment: Without seeing HTML is impossible help you, I'm sorry. Maybe some soothsayer can.

Comment: @fusion3k i think the example says enough its just a div with many other divs in it and it has to change te right </div> with where it opens :O?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to clean up HTML supplied by users, to make it valid HTML. The best tool for doing this is a client-side web browser. If you set innerHTML to any string, then read back innerHTML, the result will be valid HTML. If the users are editing a ContentEditable DIV, then innerHTML will *always* be valid HTML. Do you need to do all of this in PHP, or can you offload some of it to a web browser?

Comment: @TomRobinson Yeah i can also do it in JavaScript, Because i save the data in the datavase using a AJAX call and i made the webEditor in JavaScript so it's possible for me to change the data before sending it to the PHP save file. But how do you change it then? because it's a full webpage.? Select inner of <div id=body> en then put new <body> around it?

Comment: @TomRobinson But how am i going to do this because i also need to change HTML inside the innerHTML how can i fix these? I was starting to work with this `var html = "<html>" + $('.pageBuilder > #html').html() + "</html>";
var head = "<head>" + $('.pageBuilder #head') + "</head>";
var body = "<body>" + $('.pageBuilder #body') + "</body>";

var data = "<!DOCTYPE html>" + html;`

Comment: Are users editing the whole web page, or just certain editable portions of it? Are you using the .pageBullder class to mark the divs which should be editable?

Answer (score 1):

if your "complete code is verry verry big and uses more things than you can imagin" you may want to consider using the HTMLPurifier library (http://htmlpurifier.org/) to validate/modify the HTML so your project does not grow over your head and you can concentrate on other issues.